# How can I make a scala class implement ==?

Tags: scala

I have a non-case class that I'm trying to test for equality. It has > 22 fields so I can't use a case class in Scala 2.10.x:

```
class Row(
                 val date: String,
                 val time: String,
                 val orderId: String,
                 val id: String) extends Serializable {

  override def toString: String = {
    ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
  }
}
```

What's the simplest way of me implementing an == or equals function so I can test `row1 == row2`?

Comment: Can you add more code - how precisely are you defining your `Row` class and creating your `Row` instances?

Comment: what's the type of orderId?

Comment: The `Row` class you pasted here isn't actually a `case class`...

Comment: Yes I've just spotted that. I've been racking my brains on this. I can't in fact use case classes because I have > 22 fields...

Comment: Well in that case update your post so that you don't confuse the people that are trying to help you.

Comment: Can't you upgrade? Scala 2.11 supports case classes with arbitrary number of fields.

Comment: @Kolmar No I can't upgrade unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no choice but to implement your own `equals` and therefore `hashcode` method (not easy) since you cannot implement a `case` class. This article should help you: [object equality](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html). These are the factors you need to bear in mind:

1. Take care with the type signature of the `equals` method
2. Override the `hashCode()`
3. Avoid dependencies on mutable state
4. Should implement and use a `canEqual` method if the class is `non-final`

Comment: Why should I only implement canEqual if the class is non-final?

Comment: It is to do with comparing a `class` with its `superclass` (loose definition). If the `class` is `non-final` it means it can be extended. Therefore, it is possible that the base class and the derived class can have different implementations of their `equals` method. This breaks the contract of equals since comparing a base class with a super class will result in unexpected behavior. If you are not going to extend this class you are working with then make it final.

Comment: Otherwise, defining a `canEqual` method will redefine the notion of equality amongst classes in a hierarchy enabling you to compare objects of different types in a class hierarchy.

Comment: Still not clear TBH. I'd have thought if a class was final, it would be safer to define canEqual because it can't be subclassed.

Comment: No. If the class is final then there is no need to define canEqual. If it is non-final then you should define it. You need to read that article very carefully. There is a lot of information in it and some of it is subtle.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Row is not a case class. It is a standard class, and thus checked for equality in the standard Java way.

Try this:

```
case class Row(date: String,
               time: String,
               orderId: String,
               id: String)
```

Comment: Ah. I can't actually do that because I have > 22 fields. What's a simple way of adding equality to this class. Is there some Commons class that I can add similar to the toString method?

Answer (score 0):

Another option (though, since Row isn't a case class, still involves writing field-by-field comparison code) would be to provide an instance of the Scalaz [Equal](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Equal) typeclass.  This has the advantage of being type-safe.  For more information, check out the [Learning Scalaz series](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day1).  (The "typeclasses 102" section has an example of providing an Equal instance for a type).